# Strange crash stack trace that happens to rare users

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I am getting the following crash from a small amount of users:

```
08-29 00:56:33.321   615   636 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
08-29 00:56:33.351   615   615 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{95dbe5f8 u0 SurfaceView}
08-29 00:56:33.351   615  1129 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{95dbdde0 u0 SomeActivity}
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:635)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1012)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3897)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3829)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8490)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8367)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:9046)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:8601)
08-29 00:56:33.461   615 10350 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
08-29 00:56:33.491   615 10350 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {1.0 234mcc20mnc en_GB ldltr sw384dp w384dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.21 themeResource=null}
08-29 00:56:33.551   615  1052 I ActivityManager: Process someProcess (pid 9451) has died.
```

I got info that at least one of those users runs CyanogenMod.

This is not going through my code, so I have a hard time following.
What can cause this thing?

UPDATE:
The users that get this crash, have it consistently.
Most other users never have it.
I guess it's some device \ ROM behavior...

Comment: i too got similar crash..@SirKnigget any clues ??

Comment: Same here, however, I can reproduce it on my Nexus 4. For me it happens when i call a Native method (e.g. through NDK) inside a AsyncTask. When I move the call outside the AsyncTask it doesn't crash... Still haven't found the exact details, and why it is device related

Answer (score 0):

I ran in these exceptions too and could only reproduce them on Cyanogen. They didn't appear exactly each time I 'wanted' them to appear, but when they did, it was on Cyanogen. Also, my app had serval threads that load data. The threads were created simultaneous and when the cache of my app was cleared, the threads must access the network, instead of loading files - which means, the app never crashed when accessing the network, but while loading the files.

So I think it's an issue on Cyanogen, not Android itself. And it seems to me that the real issue here is the work load.